# Control SDL_Mix Sound Effect Volume

Tags: c++, sdl2, visual-studio

My game (coded in c++) uses SDL Mixer for its sound. But how do I make certain sounds louder than others. In the game's Main menu, one button is not immediately unlocked, creating a sound if you try to click it. But I can't hear that sound over the game's theme playing in the main menu's background. How do I lower the volume of the game's main theme song in SDL Mixer so I can hear the button press sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Mix_Volume(channel, volume)`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer_27.html) , or if you are using the special music-API, use [`Mix_VolumeMusic(volume)`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer_27.html). You cannot make things louder, as volume always defaults to the maximum (128).